# How to control IFrame behavior across browsers?

Tags: html, css, leaflet, cross-browser, folium

I wrote a script that takes rows of lat long data, image links, & other descriptors and plots those points with Folium. The images and other information are contained in popups, and the images load once the popup is opened. When I open the map files in Firefox, my images are scaled down appropriately:

[image: Proper loading behavior]

Yet when other people open the maps in Chrome or Safari, the images are hyper-zoomed to the top left *even though the browser receives the entire image properly*:

[image: Bad behavior]

I have tried injecting styling into the map html after creation, but it scales the broken image instead of properly displaying it. In the browser inspector, I have seen mention of a "user agent stylesheet", but my search for a way to control that has not been successful. My questions:

- **What is causing this loading behavior in non-Gecko browsers?**
- **How can I control how the content of these Iframes renders across browsers?**

[The map in question](https://00e9e64bac9dfd26291ee332a9f8a5a3507c803d4a74aaa506-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/rubbish-ee2d0.appspot.com/o/clean_mission_fixed-cluster.html?qk=AD5uMEumQU2WOmdtYHrWopGk-xFnZ4C75MdLXYBHwFoh2hWCScMxvGCwHrju_PApODeEHoXLFAWOGPLYlGMjP1j-AwwEAN_biV-rSyJt9LZ1qNEi0IFVjMM2qFxTYjKbLqrSN2p2OI6ytepWcPQzrZZw1nMu0pjkFRAobY_FXmov4HjjEcjjP-GHSTxDieiW-QVoBoIKxqOBIiQhfS_NFVlrEFa6U_th3taQ6npfwSVrpKNLUtKBtIBGQBFEOf0R02CITjQenCTDIMVthWKqdDo67G2xvRR7H3ONWAeW8pFY3AqBYwQVhbtOOqGdxJSfYstjI_vPCSrXmHuTerWzfeabPnFe5bRcm93Z2KrrU7ChUuDlphc5gL2eHUrj6foEJHnYUXvsgxFoI5es28xczVA-iOs2uuXp1ras4c8Wzk_FUKvsoiHK5CD9GyMq10wNXIhj6VEYL_RwZIC9qyuBeYpDBedXaW2ql19ejVzR0LQIDDQrPjEEg6tcFKsQannptQczDAhD-lLKt1lwTSy9vDQxIdy6_iEhu1s8VqdQb8Rr6gh-ptG1SXFXvGsFoIwV5ra3foVVseXrSvYOw7VQ2cCfe8pyrKGTrbn0CGDU0LLVw7lCfD3Cf-S-zvT9VFrLVmP4gK9w4u7HjAK7NUeM2dEbwEV_7g34Z-n5LQYrMVvpYEtAHZhAwruOql8KmBdiH2VedqyaxYKXsOLbVrfpdaYecKwyOWfPLjIRqfuR1_StSyaM-c6yFzxYWaZhSYDuAGrOGrdo3oD5jeiBIzZXqJKbgS4FwOb5tRC08HaJCm0l5hfaWvbL9ALUrPxr2_GqEsQ9mT207vSbR0P7-OXLkPz0NJ0AWpbc3w&isca=1)

---

The css that fixes this:

```html
<style>
#img-frame {
        transform: scale(1);
        -ms-zoom: 1.0;
        -moz-transform: scale();
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Could be anything, you need to post a [reprex] or some link so we can have a look.

Comment: The exact code used to produce the popups is in my question, what more should I be adding for an example?

Comment: A link maybe to some active site to have a look at? The CSS you posted looks fine, but for now, the error is not reproducible.